# Caching in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel-5

### **What I am doing**

My Database query is below that fetches all users from database.

```
$Users = \App\Models\User\User_Model::with("Role")->get();
```

### **Question**

In MVC CI, we could do Database Query Caching like below `$this->_ci->db->cache_on();` Is there any inbuilt method in Laravel 5.2 ?

---

---

---

## **Update**

**[As per the Docs here](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/cache#retrieving-items-from-the-cache)**...I am writing the below code to get and set the cache

```
$Categories = \Cache::get('Categories', function() {
    return \App\Models\Skill\Category_Model::all();
});
```

**Above code does not work and always get the data from database. Am I missing something ?**

Comment: Sure, look on documentation. http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/cache if you still don't know how to achieve what you want, just write I will try to explain you.

Comment: I want to `cache` Database Queries.

Comment: Look here, it's wonderfully explained what you should to do: https://bosnadev.com/2014/12/27/laravel-caching-database-queries/ it's a little old topic but still timely

Comment: The alternative way is put your `$Users` into `Cache::put('key', $Users, $minutes);` and get your values from the cache.

Comment: In MVC CI, xml gets created for infinite time, until we remove the files manually or by code. Is the time parameter optional ?

Comment: Unfornutanely no, but there is a way to do it by different method.
The forever method may be used to store an item in the cache permanently. These values must be manually removed from the cache using the forget method:

`Cache::forever('key', 'value');` and for forget `Cache::forget('key');` or entire cache by `Cache::flush();`

Comment: theoretically anywhere, can be in model or just in controller where you execute `$Users = \App\Models\User\User_Model::with("Role")->get();` ( I think, you are doing it in controller :) ) or if you want to cache it just when you application started working (without any requests) put it in **bootstrap/app.php**

Comment: I just faced problem in `getting` and `setting cache`. Can you please check the update in question ?

Comment: Try this way: `$Categories = Cache::get('Categories');`

Comment: What cache driver are you using? If it's `file`, is the directory present and writable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use it this way (just modify it to your needs):

```
$users = Cache::remember('users', $minutes, function()
{
    return DB::table('users')->get();
});
```

First time it will go to the database and next time will be loaded from cache. With *$minutes* parameter you define how many minutes should be cached before it fetches it again from database.

Comment: $users = Cache::rememberForever('users', function()
{
    return DB::table('users')->get();
});

Answer (score 1):

**[Following is the code if you want to remember it forever.](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/cache#retrieving-items-from-the-cache)**

```
$users = Cache::rememberForever('users', function()
{
    return DB::table('users')->get();
});
```